# How can I show only numbers that are dividable by 4?

Tags: arrays, vba, numbers

Only the numbers that are dividable by 4, without commas (Which means numbers like 5, 6, 7, 9 etc doesn't count)

This is the second part of my array work that I have to finish by sunday evening.

Basically after the user inputs the array numbers, **I have to show only the numbers that are dividable by 4** without commas.

This is what I have right now:

```
    Public Sub Masiivs()

    Dim Arr(4, 4) As Integer
    Dim Arg, Ard As String
    Dim X, Y, Z, M, N As Integer
    Z = 1

    For X = LBound(Arr, 1) To UBound(Arr, 1) Step 1

    For Y = LBound(Arr, 2) To UBound(Arr, 2) Step 1

        Arr(X, Y) = InputBox("Ievadiet masiva skaitli Nr. " + CStr(Z), "Datu Ievade")
        Arg = Arg & " " & Arr(X, Y)
        Z = Z + 1
    Next Y
    Arg = Arg + vbNewLine

Next X

MsgBox Arg

MsgBox ("Meklējam tos, kas dalās ar 4 bez atlikuma.")

    If X = X / 4 Then
        X = M
        Else
    End If

    If Y = Y / 4 Then
        Y = N
        Else
    End If

    Ard = Ard & CStr(M) & CStr(N)

    MsgBox Ard

End Sub
```

Apologies, I still don't understand why it doesn't count all of it as a code..

Thank you, and also thank you to all the previous people who helped me achieve this code.

Comment: Have you looked at 'mod'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub Masiivs()
    Dim Arr(4, 4) As Integer
    Dim Arg, Ard As String
    Dim X, Y, Z As Integer
    Z = 1
    Arg = ""
    Ard = ""

    For X = LBound(Arr, 1) To UBound(Arr, 1) Step 1

        For Y = LBound(Arr, 2) To UBound(Arr, 2) Step 1

            Arr(X, Y) = InputBox("Ievadiet masiva skaitli Nr. " + CStr(Z), "Datu Ievade")
            Arg = Arg & " " & Arr(X, Y)
            Z = Z + 1
        Next Y
        Arg = Arg + vbNewLine
    Next X
    MsgBox(Arg)

    MsgBox("Meklējam tos, kas dalās ar 4 bez atlikuma.")

    For Xp As Integer = 1 To 4
        For Yp As Integer = 1 To 4
            Dim Zp
            Zp = Arr(Xp, Yp)
            If (Zp Mod 4) = 0 Then
                Ard = Ard & Zp & " "
            End If
        Next
    Next

    MsgBox(Ard)
End Sub
```

Comment: I was more looking for the solution to how to show only the numbers that are dividable.

Comment: For some reason, VBA doesn't like both For's... EDIT: Nevermind, I had to get rid of the "As Integer" parts because for whatever reason they didn't like that. I had to put them in the start instead.

Answer (score 3):

[Mod](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se0w9esz.aspx) might be what you're looking for:

```
If X mod 4 = 0 Then
    ' Do something
End If
```

Comment: I was more looking for the solution to how to show only the numbers that are dividable.